# Encryption by transposing text in a grid

Tags: java, strings, programming-challenge, matrix

I wrote a Java program that given a text message will print the encoded message. The problem is described in [this link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/encryption).

Summary:

We have to write a program that will encrypt a message that do not contain space character. Assuming that \$L\$ is the length of the message we have to put characters of this string in matrix where \$\textit{columns} \cdot \textit{rows} \ge L\$ and \$\lfloor \sqrt L \rfloor \le \textit{rows} \le \textit{columns} < \lceil \sqrt L \rceil\$. To get the encrypted message we have to iterate over column and print each one as a word.

For example:

Input:  `haveaniceday`

Output: `hae and via ecy`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Encryption {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.next();
        int stringLengh = input.length();
        int lowerBound = getFloorSqrt(stringLengh);
        int upperBound = getCeilSqrt(stringLengh);
        IntRange range = new IntRange(lowerBound, upperBound);
        range = getRangeWithMinArea(range, stringLengh);
        char[][] grid = getGridEncryption(range, input);
        System.out.println(getEncryptedMessage(grid));
    }

    /**
     * return the ceil of the square root of a number.
     * 
     * @param number
     * @return
     */
    public static int getCeilSqrt(int number) {
        return (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(number));
    }

    /**
     * return the floor of the square root of a number.
     * 
     * @param number
     * @return
     */
    public static int getFloorSqrt(int number) {
        return (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(number));
    }

    /**
     * Iterate over ranges enclosed by the initial range to get the one which
     * having area greater than or equal the minimal area.
     * 
     * @param initialRange
     * 
     * @param minimalArea
     * @return
     */
    public static IntRange getRangeWithMinArea(IntRange initialRange, int minimalArea) {
        if (initialRange.getLowerBound() * initialRange.getUpperBound() < minimalArea
                && initialRange.getLowerBound() <= initialRange.getUpperBound()) {
            return getRangeWithMinArea(initialRange.incremntLowerBound(), minimalArea);
        }
        return initialRange;
    }

    /**
     * Assuming a matrix of characters this function will return a phrase where
     * each word is represented by one column. eg. input:|a|b|c| |d|e|f|
     * 
     * output: ad be cf.
     * 
     * @param grid
     * @return
     */
    private static String getEncryptedMessage(char[][] grid) {
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < grid[0].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
                if (grid[j][i] != '\u0000')
                    str.append(grid[j][i]);
            }
            str.append(" ");
        }
        return str.toString();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param range
     * @param str
     * @return
     */
    public static char[][] getGridEncryption(IntRange range, String str) {
        char[] text = str.toCharArray();
        char[][] ret = new char[range.getLowerBound()][range.getUpperBound()];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < range.getLowerBound(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < range.getUpperBound() && k < str.length(); j++) {
                ret[i][j] = text[k];
                k++;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * IntRange represents a set of integer bounded by two numbers upperBound
     * and lowerBound. such as upperBound is greater or equal lowerBound.
     */
    static class IntRange {

        private final int lowerBound;
        private final int upperBound;

        IntRange(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
            this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
            this.upperBound = upperBound;
        }

        public int getLowerBound() {
            return lowerBound;
        }

        public int getUpperBound() {
            return upperBound;
        }

        public IntRange incrementUpperBound() {
            return new IntRange(this.lowerBound, this.upperBound + 1);
        }

        public IntRange incremntLowerBound() {
            return new IntRange(this.lowerBound + 1, this.upperBound);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple typo's in your names.

```
    int stringLengh = input.length();
```

This variable should probably be called `stringLength`.

```
    public IntRange incremntLowerBound() {
```

This method should probably be called `incrementLowerBound`.

---

This section looks pretty fancy at first, but actually it's just splitting up a string.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param range
 * @param str
 * @return
 */
public static char[][] getGridEncryption(IntRange range, String str) {
    char[] text = str.toCharArray();
    char[][] ret = new char[range.getLowerBound()][range.getUpperBound()];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < range.getLowerBound(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < range.getUpperBound() && k < str.length(); j++) {
            ret[i][j] = text[k];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

There's better ways to do this than copying character for character. Consider `System.arraycopy` or `String.substring`.